# Core-data managedObjectContext - where does it come from?

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I've just been looking at Objective-c for less than a month and am definitely a newby.

I am trying to write some data that I have retrieved from a web service.  This data is called "Sens", and I have created the Core-data structures and NSManagedObject class - "Sens.h".  I have been trying several different ways of creating the Sens Object, but am stuck with determining the context (NSManagedObjectContext).   I read that it should come from the object (which is the code below) - not working.  I also tried self.managedObjectContext - also didn't work.

Herewith the code - the problem lines are:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = [Sens managedObjectContext];
Sens *newSens = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Sens" inManagedObjectContext:context];
```

The entire section of code is:

```
#import "RootViewController.h"
#import "XMLElement.h"
#import "Sens.h"


@implementation RootViewController

@synthesize xmlDocument;


-(void) xmlDocumentDelegateParsingFinished:(XMLDocument *)paramSender {
NSLog(@"Finished downloading and parsing the remote XML");
// loop through the parsed items - sens
if ([paramSender.rootElement.name isEqualToString:@"ArrayOfSensItem"]) {
    for (int i = 0; i < [paramSender.rootElement.children count]; i++) {
        XMLElement *element = [[XMLElement alloc] init];
        element = [paramSender.rootElement.children objectAtIndex:i];

        // we would like to create a new sens object that must be written away
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [Sens managedObjectContext];
        Sens *newSens = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Sens" inManagedObjectContext:context];

        for (int j = 0; j < [element.children count]; j++) {
            // another element - this is the actually interesting stuff
            XMLElement *childElement = [[XMLElement alloc]init];
            childElement = [element.children objectAtIndex:j];

            if (newSens != nil) {
                // body
                if ([childElement.name isEqualToString:@"body"])
                    newSens.body = childElement.text;

                // company code list
                newSens.company = @"";

                // headline
                newSens.heading = childElement.text;

                // newsid
                newSens.sensID = (NSNumber *)[childElement.text intValue];

                // sens date
                NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
                [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
                newSens.sensDate = [dateFormat dateFromString:childElement.text];

                // display
                NSLog(@"Name: %@",childElement.name);
            }

            [childElement release];
        }

        // save the unsaved changes into the context
        NSError *savingError = nil;
        if ([context save:&savingError] == YES){
            NSLog(@"Successfully saved the SENS item: %@",newSens.sensID);
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Failed to create a new SENS record.");
        }

        [newSens release];



        // release the element
        [element release];

    }
}
NSLog(@"Root element: %@",paramSender.rootElement.name);
}
```

Thanks - I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using a Core Data template from apple the easiest way is to get it from the AppDelegate, like this:

```
context = [(AppDelegate_Shared *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
```

a cleaner solution would be to create a instance variable and synthesized g/setters.
You can then pass a `NSManagedObjectContext` instance (most likely from the AppDelegate) to the viewController when you create it.

Comment: +1 The Core Data using templates are the best way to understand the basic Core Data implementation.

Comment: Thank you @fluchtpunkt.   I replaced AppDelegate_Shared with Sens and it seems to be working.
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [(Sens *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];

Comment: @Wonderboy I guess `Sens` is your `NSManagedObject`? If this is the case it's pure coincidence that this works (because Sens has a managedObjectContext property too). You should use the class of the appdelegate. If you don't have a universal project with core data the class should be YourProjectNameAppDelegate. Of course you have to replace YourProjectName with the actual name of your project. Don't forget to import the header named `YourProjectNameAppDelegate.h`

Comment: you are right.  I mistakenly got it from Sens which is a class inheriting NSManagedObject.   Now - I have instantiated my appDelegate class and used appDelegate.managedObjectContext and this seems to be working.  Thanks so much.